# Why can OpenVPN clients with static (vpn)-IP not ping the server and clients with DHCP (vpn)-ip can?

Tags: routing, openvpn, ping

I'm building an OpenVPN network. The idea is that servers which are connected to the VPN get an fixed IP and the clients (which use services of the servers) get dhcp ip's.

- The servers should get an IP in `10.10.0.1 - 10.10.0.254`
- The clients should get an IP in `10.10.1.1 - 10.10.255.254`

My current setup looks like this:

- OpenVPN server 10.10.0.1
- Application server 10.10.0.20 <- static via ccd
- Client 10.10.1.2 <- DHCP

I achieved that my clients get an DHCP address in the correct range. They are also able to ping the OpenVPN server and visa versa.

I was also able to configure client specific config's for the servers so they get their static IP but for some reason they cannot ping the OpenVPN server and i can also not ping the client from the OpenVPN server.

Can someone help me to find what i configured wrong?

**OpenVPN configuration files**

OpenVPN server config:

```
port 3194
proto udp
dev tun
mode server

ca server_cert/ca.crt
cert server_cert/ovpn-server.crt
key server_cert/ovpn-server.key  # This file should be kept secret
dh server_cert/dh.pem

tls-server
cipher AES-256-CBC

ifconfig 10.10.0.1 255.255.0.0
ifconfig-pool 10.10.1.1 10.10.255.254

route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0
push "route-gateway 10.10.0.1 255.255.0.0"
push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"

ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt

client-config-dir ccd
client-to-client
duplicate-cn

keepalive 10 120

persist-key
persist-tun

status openvpn-status.log
log-append  /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 6
explicit-exit-notify 1
```

My client specific config for the application servers:

```
ifconfig-push 10.10.0.20 10.10.0.1
```

My client.conf (used on the application servers)

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
port 3194
remote vpn.domain.com 3194
nobind
cipher AES-256-CBC

ca keys/ca.crt
cert /etc/openvpn/keys/ngin-web01.crt
key /etc/openvpn/keys/ngin-web01.key

log-append /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 6
```

**Routes**

OpenVPN Server (10.10.0.1):

```
root@ovpn-srv01:/home/axxmin# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.20.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens18
10.10.0.0       255.255.0.0     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.128.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens18
255.255.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0

root@ovpn-srv01:/home/axxmin# routel
         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
     10.10.0.0/ 16     255.255.0.0                                     tun0
    255.255.0.0                          10.10.0.1   kernel     link   tun0
      10.10.0.1              local       10.10.0.1   kernel     host   tun0 local
        default        10.128.20.1                   static           ens18
   10.128.20.0/ 24                     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18
    10.128.20.0          broadcast     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18 local
    10.128.20.6              local     10.128.20.6   kernel     host  ens18 local
  10.128.20.255          broadcast     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18 local
      127.0.0.0          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
     127.0.0.0/ 8            local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
      127.0.0.1              local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
127.255.255.255          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
            ::1                                      kernel              lo
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel           ens18
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            tun0
            ::1              local                   kernel              lo local
fe80::1083:7fff:fedd:70c0              local                   kernel           ens18 local
fe80::b24c:97a4:281:de41              local                   kernel            tun0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                     ens18 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      tun0 local
```

Application server (10.10.0.20)

```
root@ovpn-srv01:/home/axxmin# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.20.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens18
10.10.0.0       255.255.0.0     255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.128.20.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens18
255.255.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0

root@ovpn-srv01:/home/axxmin# routel
         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
     10.10.0.0/ 16     255.255.0.0                                     tun0
    255.255.0.0                          10.10.0.1   kernel     link   tun0
      10.10.0.1              local       10.10.0.1   kernel     host   tun0 local
        default        10.128.20.1                   static           ens18
   10.128.20.0/ 24                     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18
    10.128.20.0          broadcast     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18 local
    10.128.20.6              local     10.128.20.6   kernel     host  ens18 local
  10.128.20.255          broadcast     10.128.20.6   kernel     link  ens18 local
      127.0.0.0          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
     127.0.0.0/ 8            local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
      127.0.0.1              local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
127.255.255.255          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
            ::1                                      kernel              lo
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel           ens18
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            tun0
            ::1              local                   kernel              lo local
fe80::1083:7fff:fedd:70c0              local                   kernel           ens18 local
fe80::b24c:97a4:281:de41              local                   kernel            tun0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                     ens18 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      tun0 local
```

Client (10.10.1.2):

```
root@client-device:/home/pi# route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         10.128.60.1     0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
10.10.0.0       10.10.1.1       255.255.0.0     UG    0      0        0 tun0
10.10.1.1       0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.128.60.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0

root@client-device:/home/pi# routel
         target            gateway          source    proto    scope    dev tbl
     10.10.0.0/ 16       10.10.1.1                                     tun0
      10.10.1.1                          10.10.1.2   kernel     link   tun0
      10.10.1.2              local       10.10.1.2   kernel     host   tun0 local
        default        10.128.60.1    10.128.60.33     dhcp            eth0
   10.128.60.0/ 24                    10.128.60.33     dhcp     link   eth0
    10.128.60.0          broadcast    10.128.60.33   kernel     link   eth0 local
   10.128.60.33              local    10.128.60.33   kernel     host   eth0 local
  10.128.60.255          broadcast    10.128.60.33   kernel     link   eth0 local
      127.0.0.0          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
     127.0.0.0/ 8            local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
      127.0.0.1              local       127.0.0.1   kernel     host     lo local
127.255.255.255          broadcast       127.0.0.1   kernel     link     lo local
            ::1                                      kernel              lo
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            eth0
        fe80::/ 64                                   kernel            tun0
            ::1              local                   kernel              lo local
fe80::20d4:6b14:ff16:e230              local                   kernel            tun0 local
fe80::65cf:ce3:fc9f:20fa              local                   kernel            eth0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      eth0 local
        ff00::/ 8                                                      tun0 local
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't specify a topology in the server config file, Openvpn works in `net30` mode, which is the default. In this mode, every client will be assigned an IP from a /30 subnet, the other usable IP in the subnet will be allocated for the p2p address of that tunnel. The parameters of the `ifconfig` and `route` commands in this mode are "local-ip peer-ip", and not "local-ip netmask".

In order for your config to work, you need to include the

```
topology subnet
```

line in your server config, so the `ifconfig` and `route` commands will be mostly all right. The only exception is the static address allocation for the client, which should be

```
ifconfig-push 10.10.0.20 255.255.0.0
```

<strike>And you don't need to push the `route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0` command, since the netmask and the IP in `ifconfig-push` sets that route already.</strike>
Edit / correction: You *do* need to propagate the route, it happens automatically only if you use the `server` directive in the config. My bad.

You probably need to change the `ifconfig-pool` directive as well, for two reasons. First, the `10.10.1.1` address should not part of the pool, since it is the IP of the VPN server. Second, since you don't use the default /24 netmask, it is probably a good idea to specify that as well:

```
ifconfig-pool 10.10.1.2 10.10.1.254 255.255.0.0
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After these changes i can ping between the ovpn-server and the static client but only for a short moment after `service openvpn restart`. After arround 10 to 20 seconds, i cannot ping anymore. Do you have any idea what the cause could be? The ping between the ovpn-server and the client still works stable.

Comment: When i remove the `push "route 10.10.0.0 255.255.0.0"`, i cannot ping from the client to the server anymore. When i check `route -n` the route/gateway is missing then. I decided to keep pushing that route..

Comment: The client/server logs should give you some clue. I can only guess about the connection loss. The most probable cause is that two clients use the same CN for connection, so the static IP gets assigned from one to another, which makes the connection to hang on one of the clients (while the tunnel still active).

Comment: The OpenVPN server logs tell me this: MULTI: bad source address from client [10.10.0.20], packet dropped. I found that this hangs together with the fact there is no internal OpenVPN route to this client? How can i solve this?, how is it possible that it works for a short period?

Comment: I've edited the answer, made some changes about specifying the `ifconfig-pool`. I would guess the lack of an internal route as well, but then I don't know how it doesn't fail immediately, so I'm not sure that the edited post will help you, but give it a try :)

Comment: Thanks for the edit/update and your support. The updates you made to your answer make sense! Unfortunatly this did not solve my `bad source address` error. I will open a new question for this as the actual question is answered and the initial issue is solved. Link to the new question -> https://serverfault.com/questions/1035178/why-logs-my-openvpn-server-multi-bad-source-address-from-client